# Python regex to match punctuation at end of string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, match

I need to match if a sentence starts with a capital and ends with [?.!] in Python.

**EDIT** It must have [?.!] **only** at end **but allow other punctuation in the sentence**

```
import re
s = ['This sentence is correct.','This sentence is not correct', 'Something is !wrong! here.','"This is an example of *correct* sentence."']

# What I tried so for is:
for i in s:
    print(re.match('^[A-Z][?.!]$', i) is not None)
```

It does not work, after some changes I know the `^[A-Z]` part is correct but matching the punctuation at the end is incorrect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I made it working for myself, and just for clarification or if other people have the same problem this is what did the trick for me:

```
re.match('^[A-Z][^?!.]*[?.!]$', sentence) is not None
```

**Explanation:**
Where `^[A-Z]` looks for a Capital at start

`'[^?!.]*'` means everything in between start and end is ok except things containing `?` or `!` or `.`

`[?.!]$` must end with `?` or `!` or `.`

Comment: Using a negative look-ahead followed by `.` is an intricate and probably inefficient way of achieving that. Consider using a negative character class: `[^?!.]*`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below regex.

```
^[A-Z][\w\s]+[?.!]$
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/jpqTQ0/2

---

```
import re
s = ['This sentence is correct.','this sentence does not start with capital','This sentence is not correct']

# What I tried so for is:
for i in s:
    print(re.match('^[A-Z][\w\s]+[?.!]$', i) is not None)
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
```

[Working code demo](http://ideone.com/7DTs5q)

Comment: What if I want to not have [?.!] appear anywhere else in the string, but only at the end.

Comment: Then also the above regex will work fine. Check the regex demo link and try your test string there.

Comment: But it won't allow "," or ";" or quotes inside the sentence, either.

Comment: @lenz Yes that is why I posted an awnser myself and updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex checks for a single digit in the range `[A-Z]`. You should change to something like:

```
^[A-Z].*[?.!]$
```

Change the `.*` to whatever you want to match between the capital letter and the punctuation at the end of the string.

Comment: `.*` must always be avoided.